# Kafka Streams - override default addSink implementation / custom producer

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

It is my first post to this here and I am not sure if this was covered here before, but here goes: I have a Kafka Streams application, using Processor API, following the topology below:

```
1. Consume data from an input topic (processor.addSource())
2. Inserts data into a DB (processor.addProcessor())
3. Produce its process status to an output topic (processor.addSink())
```

App works big time, however, for traceability purposes, I need to have in the logs the moment kstreams produced a message to the output topic, as well as its RecordMetaData (topic, partition, offset).

Example below:

```
KEY="MY_KEY" OUTPUT_TOPIC="MY-OUTPUT-TOPIC" PARTITION="1" OFFSET="1000" STATUS="SUCCESS"
```

I am not sure if there is a way to override the default kafka streams producer to add this logging or maybe creating my own producer to plug it on the addSink process. I partially achieved it by implementing my own ExceptionHandler (default.producer.exception.handler), but it only covers the exceptions.

Thanks in advance,

Guilherme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure the streams application to use a `ProducerInterceptor`, then you should be able to get the information you need. Specifically, implementing the [onAcknowledgement()](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html#onAcknowledgement-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata-java.lang.Exception-) will provide access to everything you listed above.

To configure interceptors in a streams application:

```java
 Properties props = new Properties();
 // add this configuration in addition to your other streams configs

props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG), Collections.singletonList(MyProducerInterceptor.class));
```

You can provide more than one interceptor if desired, just add the class name and change the list implementation from a singleton to a regular `List`. Execution of the interceptors follows the order of the classes in the list.

EDIT: Just to be clear, you can override the provided `Producer` in Kafka Streams via the [KafkaClientSupplier interface](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaClientSupplier.html), but IMHO using an interceptor is the cleaner approach.  But which direction to go is up to you.  You pass in your `KafkaClientSupplier` in an [overloaded Kafka Streams constructor](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#KafkaStreams-org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology-java.util.Properties-org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaClientSupplier-).

Comment: Definitely going with the Interceptor. As it's for auditing purposes only, I also don't see a reason to override the default behavior. It worked big time, thanks a lot!